# Sorting a List of Lists

Tags: python, sorting

I have this list of lists:

```
data = [['john','1','2', 2.45434], ['jack','1.3','2.2', 4.45434],
        ['josh','2','3', 3.45434]]
```

I want to sort it by the very last decimal number in each inner list. How can I do this?

Comment: In your case, the index is `-1` instead of `1`, but the concept is the same as the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `key` in the `sorted` function as the last element of the sub lists:

```
sorted(data, key = lambda x: x[-1])

# [['john', '1', '2', 2.45434],
#  ['josh', '2', '3', 3.45434],
#  ['jack', '1.3', '2.2', 4.45434]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may sort the existing "data" list by `.sort()` function of `list` using `lambda` function as:

```
data = [['john','1','2', 2.45434],['jack','1.3','2.2', 4.45434], ['josh','2','3', 3.45434]]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
# data = [['john', '1', '2', 2.45434], ['josh', '2', '3', 3.45434], ['jack', '1.3', '2.2', 4.45434]]
```